# [Proof]if p and q are odd prime, and q=2p+1,then -4 is primitive root of q

Tags: primitive-roots

how to proof if p and q are odd prime, and q=2p+1, then -4 is primitive root of q.
I think quadratic residue of q is useful, but I cant use it effectively.
if for example. p=3, then q=7, and the number -4(mod 7) is the primitive of 7.

my try is:
if a is quadratic residue of q then a^((q-1)/2) = a^p = 1 (mod q). and if r is primitive root of q then there exists integer k such that r^2k=a (mod q)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $-3$ is a primitive root modulo $p=2q+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648616/show-that-3-is-a-primitive-root-modulo-p-2q1)

Comment: Note:  the duplicate addresses $-3$, not $-4$, but the argument is the same.  Actually, your case is simpler as you can skip the Legendre symbol part.